# magento 2 : Place order using REST API and stripe payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, rest-api, place-order, stripe

We are working on mobile which use magento 2 REST API. In which we are facing issue while try to place order using Stripe payment method. For stripe we are using magenest stripe extension.

REST API call for guest user is :
https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/aHdNbZDggtknHuhZWwEfQvvHQz8JVZnb/order

Parameter is :

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
       "additional_data":{
           "number": "4111111111111111",
           "exp_month": "10",
           "exp_year": "30",
           "cvv": "123",
         }
    "method": "magenest_stripe"
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
    "massage" : "No such token: false"
}
```

So please help us to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you resolved your query?

Comment: Not yet, I am still looking for solution,

Comment: I wrote the two cases in answer why this issue occur. Have you checked and troubleshooted both cases?

Comment: @MuhammadHasham yes we have test it by both way but we are getting same error.

Comment: @MuhammadHasham do you think we have problem in request body?

Comment: @JalpeshPatel did you able to resolve this issue? Please add your own answer and mark as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Case 1

This is an issue with your integration and not the code or the library and the best solution for this is to double check your API keys. You are likely creating a token with the Publishable key from one account and then trying to use it with the Secret key of another account.

> Case 2

Another case of this error usually appears when you are connected to Stripe via Test mode, but with your Live settings.

**I hope this will help**